# Solution of a sixth degree polynomial

Tags: equation-solving

I want to get the solution to a 6th degree polynomial in a certain range.

I have the following code

```
DefiningExpression = Simplify[r^4 (-3 M + r)^2 - a^4 (-1 + x) (M + r)^2 + 
  2 a^2 r^2 (3 (-1 + x) M^2 - 2 M r - (-1 + x) r^2)];
sol = Solve[DefiningExpression == 0, r];
CloseBound = 2 M (1 + Cos[2/3 ArcCos[-a/M]]);
FarBound = 2 M (1 + Cos[2/3 ArcCos[a/M]]);

Plot[{Lookup[sol[[1]], r], Lookup[sol[[2]], r], Lookup[sol[[3]], r],  Lookup[sol[[4]], r]}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

I want to solve the `DefiningExpression` for $r$ in terms of $x$. Unfortunately this is a no-so-friendly 6th degree polynomial, so we won't find any analytic solutions. The additional requirement is that only the following values of $r$ are of interest:
$$r \in [2 M (1 + \cos[2/3 \arccos[-a/M]]), 2 M (1 + \cos[2/3 \arccos[a/M]])].$$

When plotting this, we get that the solutions between these bounds are spread out between the different solutions of `sol`:[image]

Here $a=0.7$, $M=1$.

Also the constraints on $a$ and $M$ are that $r>M>a>0$.

How can I get a solution of $r$ in terms of $x$ where $r$ lies within this range?

Comment: Please post the *Mathematica* code for your equation so that we don't have to type it in from scratch.  Also, are there ranges of $a$ and $M$ that are of interest?

Comment: @JimB: You are completely right. This is not a good practice not to present a Mathematica code. However,  a TeX code in the text can be seen  by  clicking the right  button of a mouse and choosing `Show Math As/ TeX Commands` and can be copied. In the question under consideration the TeX code is very close to Mathematica code.

Comment: I can't believe I'm saying this:  Maybe I'm more picky than you.  I also like to be able to assume that the OP has a copy of *Mathematica*.

Comment: @JimB: The OP wrote " I'll test this out as soon as possible!" so one may draw the conclusion the OP has  access to Mathematica.

Comment: @JimB I was in a rush and didn't know immediately how to write down mathematica code in stackexchange so I opted for LaTeX. I'm also new to this site of stack as you may see. I'm updating the post now.

Comment: @Geigercounter Wouldn't it be much simpler to solve for `x[r]`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann In the context of the calculation you start from $x(r)$, so I'm trying to invert that equation

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating `M` and `a`, this can be done as follows.

```
M = 3; a = 1; Reduce[r^4 (-3 M + r)^2 - a^4 (-1 + x) (M + r)^2 + 
2 a^2 r^2 (3 (-1 + x) M^2 - 2 M r - (-1 + x) r^2) == 0 && 
r >= 2 M (1 + Cos[2/3*ArcCos[-a/M]]) && r <= 2 M (1 + Cos[2/3*ArcCos[a/M]]), r, Reals]
```

> `(x == 0 &&  r == Root[3 + # - 9 #^2 + #^3& , 3, 0]) || (0 < x <  Root[-4096576 + 3799632 # + 272724 #^2 + 26407 #^3& , 1,  0] && (r ==  Root[9 - 9 x + (6 - 6 x) #1 + (-53 + 53 x) #1^2 -  12 #1^3 + (83 - 2 x) #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 1] ||  r == Root[ 9 - 9 x + (6 - 6 x) #1 + (-53 + 53 x) #1^2 -  12 #1^3 + (83 - 2 x) #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + #1^6 &,  2])) || (Root[-4096576 + 3799632 # + 272724 #^2 + 26407 #^3& ,  1, 0] <= x <  1 && (r ==  Root[9 - 9 x + (6 - 6 x) #1 + (-53 + 53 x) #1^2 -  12 #1^3 + (83 - 2 x) #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 3] ||  r == Root[ 9 - 9 x + (6 - 6 x) #1 + (-53 + 53 x) #1^2 -  12 #1^3 + (83 - 2 x) #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 4])) || (x ==  1 && (r == Root[-12 + 81 # - 18 #^2 + #^3& , 2, 0] ||  r == Root[-12 + 81 # - 18 #^2 + #^3& , 3, 0]))`

Addition.For `M = Pi; a = 1.;` and with `Chop` the result is

> `(x == 0 &&  r == 9.28055) || (0 < x <  0.999592 && (r ==  Root[2.75795*10^23 -  2.75795*10^23 x + (1.75577*10^23 -  1.75577*10^23 x) #1 + (-1.62683*10^24 +  1.62683*10^24 x) #1^2 -  3.51153*10^23 #1^3 + (2.53804*10^24 -  5.58878*10^22 x) #1^4 - 5.2673*10^23 #1^5 +  2.79439*10^22 #1^6 &, 1] ||  r == Root[ 2.75795*10^23 -  2.75795*10^23 x + (1.75577*10^23 -  1.75577*10^23 x) #1 + (-1.62683*10^24 +  1.62683*10^24 x) #1^2 -  3.51153*10^23 #1^3 + (2.53804*10^24 -  5.58878*10^22 x) #1^4 - 5.2673*10^23 #1^5 +  2.79439*10^22 #1^6 &, 2])) || (0.999592 <= x <=  1. && (r ==  Root[2.75795*10^23 -  2.75795*10^23 x + (1.75577*10^23 -  1.75577*10^23 x) #1 + (-1.62683*10^24 +  1.62683*10^24 x) #1^2 -  3.51153*10^23 #1^3 + (2.53804*10^24 -  5.58878*10^22 x) #1^4 - 5.2673*10^23 #1^5 +  2.79439*10^22 #1^6 &, 3] ||  r == Root[ 2.75795*10^23 -  2.75795*10^23 x + (1.75577*10^23 -  1.75577*10^23 x) #1 + (-1.62683*10^24 +  1.62683*10^24 x) #1^2 -  3.51153*10^23 #1^3 + (2.53804*10^24 -  5.58878*10^22 x) #1^4 - 5.2673*10^23 #1^5 +  2.79439*10^22 #1^6 &, 4])) || (x == 1. && r == 10.5178)`

`10^24` does not make a good impression at me.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test this out as soon as possible!

Comment: It seems to give the correct answer, but plugging this into `RegionPlot` doesn't seem to work though...

Comment: @Geigercounter: Plot by parts. `Plot[Root[2.75795*10^23-2.75795*10^23 x+(1.75577*10^23-1.75577*10^23 x) #1+(-1.62683*10^24+1.62683*10^24 x) #1^2-3.51153*10^23 #1^3+(2.53804*10^24-5.58878*10^22 x) #1^4-5.2673*10^23 #1^5+2.79439*10^22 #1^6&,1],{x,0,0.999592}]` works well to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is advantageous to solve the expression for x first and introduce new parameters `a -> \[Alpha] M, r -> \[Rho] M`:

```
solx = x /. Solve[DefiningExpression == 0, x][[1]] /. {a -> \[Alpha] M, r -> \[Rho] M} // Simplify[#, M > 0] &
```

$x=\frac{\left(\alpha ^2 (\rho +1)+(\rho -3) \rho ^2\right)^2}{2 \alpha ^2
   \rho ^2 \left(\rho ^2-3\right)+\alpha ^4 (\rho +1)^2}$

The constraints transform too

```
cond1=\[Rho] > 1 > \[Alpha] > 0(* from r>M>a>0 *)
cond2=2   (1 + Cos[2/3*ArcCos[-\[Alpha]]]) <= \[Rho] <=2   (1 + Cos[2/3*ArcCos[\[Alpha]]])
```

There is only one parameter `1>\[Alpha]>0` left!

```
 plot[\[Alpha]_?NumericQ] := 
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{\[Rho], ((-3 + \[Rho]) \[Rho]^2 + \[Alpha]^2 (1 + \
\[Rho]))^2/(\[Alpha]^4 (1 + \[Rho])^2 + 
     2 \[Alpha]^2 \[Rho]^2 (-3 + \[Rho]^2))}], {\[Rho], 1, 5}, {x, 0, 
   1}, RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{\[Rho], x}, \[Rho] > 1 > \[Alpha] > 0 && 
     2 (1 + Cos[(2 ArcCos[-\[Alpha]])/3]) <= \[Rho] <= 
      2 (1 + Cos[(2 ArcCos[\[Alpha]])/3])], FrameLabel -> {r/M, x}, 
  PlotLabel -> "a/M=" <> ToString[\[Alpha]]]
```

examplary simulation `\[Alpha]=a/M=0.7`

```
plot[0.7]
```

[image]